# Counting elliptic curves over finite fields with a prescribed number of points

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, and let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order in $K$ of discriminant $D$ and class number $h(\mathcal{O})$. Then the *Hurwitz-Kronecker* class number can be defined as
$$
H(D):=\sum_{\mathcal{O}\subset \mathcal{O}' \subset \mathcal{O}_K} \frac{2}{\# \mathcal{O'}^\times} h(\mathcal{O}').
$$

A beautiful result attributed to Deuring (see Theorem 14.18 of Cox's *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*) gives the following formula for the number of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with exactly $N$ rational points over $\mathbb{F}_p$:
$$
\frac{p-1}{2} H\left((p+1-N)^2-4p\right).
$$

**Question**: Is there a generalization of this result for the number of elliptic curves over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of prime-power order with a given number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-ratoinal points?

Remark: There are several related results due to Waterhouse, Schoof, Lenstra, and others, which give formulas for the number of isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with a given number of $\mathbb{F}_q$-points.